# PHP Constant __FILE__ returns wrong path

Tags: constants

On my new webserver it seems that the `__FILE__` constant doesn't work properly.

If I open a file containing: `<? echo (__FILE__); ?>` under the adresse of http://www.nico-webdesign.de/test.php it returns me /homepages/40/d467088061/htdocs/nicowebdesign/test.php.

Can that be right?

Comment: It most certainly is right :-). `__FILE__` expands to the file system path of the file it is contained in, not the URL you accessed it with.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that appears to be right.

`__FILE__` is a constant containing the full pathname to the file it is used in.

Your question states that the path returned is "wrong". What path should `__FILE__` return according to you? Keep symlinks in mind: `__FILE__` returns the full, real, non-symlinked path, even if you used a symlink to go to that path and created that file.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

> Since PHP 4.0.2, `__FILE__` always contains an absolute path with symlinks resolved

If you would like the URL used to access the file from the browser, see:
[Get the full URL in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/php-get-the-full-url)